# How to dump entire appsettings.json file in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am trying to create a simple `GET` API endpoint which will return the JSON of the current environment `appsettings.json` file, for example for the development environment it will return the contents of `appsettings.Development.json` file and for production environment it will return the contents of `appsettings.Production.json` file.

I don't know a nice way to dump the entire config file. What I know though is ways to read single config values through the injected `config["Key"]` or read a section through

```
config.GetSection("SectionName").Get<MyCustomSectionClass>()
```

approach. These options are not feasible as the file is big and the content may change.

This is an ASP.NET Core 6 Core Web API application, created through the default Visual Studio template.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return entire `appsettings.xxx.json` file, You can try this simple demo. I not sure if there is a better method, But this method works well in my project.

```
        using Newtonsoft.Json;


        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

        public WeatherForecastController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;
        }

           
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            if (_env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "appsettings.Development.json");
                string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
                object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                return Ok(jsonObject);
            }else if (_env.IsProduction())
            {
                //read from appsettings.Production.json
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                //..........
                return Ok();
            }

            
        }
```

[image]